# jQuery post() with serialize and array of data

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

**i am unable to get collection value during post in mvc 3.
 it is returning null.**

```
$.post("/Work/Post", { vm: $('#myForm').serializeArray(), 'collection': ['a', 'b', 'c'] });

//Or


var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({ name: 'collection', value: ['a', 'b', 'c'] });
$.post("/Work/Post", data);

//Or

var data = $('#myForm').serializeArray();
data.push({ name: 'collection[]', value: ['a', 'b', 'c'] });
$.post("/Work/Post", data);
```

Comment: Try using .ajax directly rather than .post and see if you get something

Comment: Use Firebug, or a similar tool, to see what data is being sent as part of the request, and check that it matches the format you're expecting/needing it to be on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
                var model = $('#myForm').serializeArray();

                $.map(['a', 'b', 'c'], function (val, i) {
                    return model.push({ "name": "collection[" + i + "]", "value": val });
                });

                $.post("/Work/Post", model);
                //OR
                $.post("/Work/Post", model, function (data) {
                    //After Success
                });
```

Comment: More people should know the name value pair usage of jquery ajax data model.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem when passing arrays.

Instead of using `$.post` use `$.ajax` and set the `traditional` option = `true` ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Work/",
    traditional: true,
    data: { collection: ['a','b','c'] }
});
```

The `traditional: true` option is important

Answer (score 3):

I banged my head against this wall for months with the regular .ajax() call.

I eventually found out that you need to set `traditional: true` in the params list for $.ajax(). (see the "traditional" heading here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Since there is no params list for $.post(), I'm not sure you can do this with $.post(). But it's not much more code to use $.ajax().

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me. You can use <strike>serializeArray()</strike> serializeJSON() as below and set that to the data element. Observe the **formData** variable.

```
var formData = $('#inputForm').serializeJSON();
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url: server_side_url,
    cache:false,
    traditional: true,
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log("successfully processed.");
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error){
        console.log("error occurred.");
    }
});
```